# Number Line using Java Graphics API

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, window

I am trying to create a number line with labelled x-axis.Two problems:

1. Everything works fine for 0-9. But anything after that, the numbers get squashed together and not properly oriented on the scale.
2. My main axis line tends to disappear every time I try maximizing my window or at times it just wouldn't appear at all.Every time any of these happen, I have to re-compile my code and it works just fine.

Any help with the above problems will be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
* @author Emil Shirima
*
*/
public class Drawing extends JFrame {

/**
 * @param args
 */
int width = 300, height = 300, spacing = 10;
int x1 = 0, y1 = 150, x2 = 300, y2 = 150;

public Drawing() {
    setTitle("Trial");
    setSize(width, height);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics brush) {
    brush.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    x1 = 10;
    y1 = 150;
    x2 = 10;
    y2 = 130;
    // brush.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
        String ID = Integer.toString(i);
        x1 = x2 += spacing;
        brush.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        if (i < 10) {
            brush.drawString(ID, x1 - 3, y2 + 40);
        } else {
            // With the below implementation, the numbers overlap each other
            // and are not properly oriented on the axis
            brush.drawString(ID, x1 - 3, y2 + 40);
            // TODO: I need to resize the numbers after 10 so as they fit
            // properly on the scale
        }

    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Drawing draw_object = new Drawing();

}
```

---

Current implementation:

[image]

Maximized GUI:

[image]

Comment: Please see edits to answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main problem:

- You change x1, x2 within your paint method, and these changes will persist on the next painting. In other words, you're changing the state of the object within a rendering method, something that you must avoid doing.
- You're using "magic" numbers making your program difficult to debug.

Other associated problems:

- You're drawing directly in a JFrame, something that the Swing painting tutorials tell you exactly not to do since there are risks of significant side effects.
- Instead draw in a JPanel's paintComponent method method.
- You're not calling any super painting method, thus breaking the painting chain.

If you want the number line to extend through the component, get the component's size in the painting method (again, paintComponent) and use that to help determine the placement of the line.

Also consider sprinkling in a little FontMetrics to help place your numeric text. For example the following code creates a realizable number line:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SimpleNumberLinePanel extends JPanel {

   private static final int PREF_W = 800;
   private static final int PREF_H = 300;
   private static final int GAP = 10;
   private static final int START = 0;
   private static final int END = 12;
   private static final int VERT_LINE_HEIGHT = 20;
   private static final Font FONT = new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.BOLD, 14);
   private static final int TEXT_GAP = 2;

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      // call super method
      super.paintComponent(g);

      int width = getWidth();
      int height = getHeight();

      // initialize these guys each time paintComponent is called
      int x1 = GAP;
      int y1 = height / 2;
      int x2 = width - 2 * GAP;
      int y2 = y1;
      g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);

      for (int i = START; i <= END; i++) {
         int x = (i * (x2 - x1)) / (END - START) + GAP;
         drawNumberAndLine(g, i, x, y1, VERT_LINE_HEIGHT);
      }
   }

   private void drawNumberAndLine(Graphics g, int number, int x, int y,
         int vertLineHeight) {
      int x1 = x;
      int y1 = y;
      int x2 = x;
      int y2 = y - vertLineHeight;
      g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);

      String text = String.valueOf(number);
      g.setFont(FONT);
      FontMetrics fontMetrics = g.getFontMetrics();
      int textX = x - fontMetrics.stringWidth(text) / 2;
      int textY = y + fontMetrics.getHeight() + TEXT_GAP;
      g.drawString(text, textX, textY);
   }

   @Override // make GUI bigger
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
         return super.getPreferredSize();
      }
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Number Line");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new SimpleNumberLinePanel());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Being new to the Graphics API, the sample code was extremely helpful and it helped me understand the API better.